# winforms - show same form twice?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a quick and dirty winforms app I wrote,
Which has a lot of controls logic & internal logic written within the Form() class.

I have a need to just open the same form twice (Where one form will be like a reference to other), and I'm looking for another quick and dirty solution.

That the code within my Program class:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Main());
        //Can I run Main() form a again as reference to the intial form?
    }
}
```

Yes, I'm aware best practice mentions I should separate to user controls, etc, please don't judge.
Assistance is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best option for you is to add Click method on your form and there create a new instance of your form and show it

```
 private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var frm = new Form1();
            frm.Show();
        }
```

now you can click everywhere on the form and it will open another instance of it

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna accept this answer, It's what I ended up doing, I enhanced it bit with passing the current form as a constructor argument so I could set the references to the parent form objects.

Answer (score 1):

you actually can, provided that the main objective is to just run another instance of the same form - in this case, the `Main`.

you can do this by hooking it up on the `Main`'s instance prior to loading from the `Application.Run(...);` method of the `Program.cs` file, see below sample code snippet.

```
public void Main_Load()
{
    var newForm = new Main();
    newForm.Show();
}
```

its important not to use `ShowDialog();` to not block the first Form.

Hope i got it right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to go with Nii solution keep in mind recursive, because the solution as is will never end. 
You are going to need some control for only showing one form, something like this could work:

```
static int control = 0;
...
if (control == 0)
{
control = 1;
var newForm = new Main();
newForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

you need to do that like this

```
static class Program
{

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var thread = new Thread(ThreadStart);            
        thread.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start(); 
        Application.Run(new Form1());

    }
    private static void ThreadStart()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form2()); 
    }

}
```

you can also Start the other forms from the `Form.Load` event of FirstForm.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer